# Tell yum to install the exact version of my package dependencies

Tags: redhat, installation, yum, rpm

I'd like to install a package named `pA`.

- Package `pA-1.0.0-0` depends on package `pB-1.0.0-0`.
- On a yum repository, one can find both `pB-1.0.0-0` and `pB-1.1.0-0`.
- Package `pA-1.0.0-0` is not compatible with `pB-1.1.0-0`, and this information is not mentioned in the RPM of `pA` because `pB-1.1.0-0` did not exist back when `pA` was packaged.

This is a problem when trying to install `pA` with `yum`:

```
$ yum localinstall pA-1.0.0-0.el7.x86_64.rpm
...
Resolving Dependencies
-> Processing Dependency: pB >= 1.0.0 for package: pA-1.0.0-0.el7.x86_64
--> Package pB.x86_64 0:1.1.0-0.el7 will be installed # <-- version 1.1! ho no!
```

**Is there a command line option in `yum` to ask it to install the specific version demanded for its dependencies?**
<sup>Specifically here, to install `pA-1.0.0-0.el7.x86_64` rather than `pA-1.1.0-0.el7.x86_64`.</sup>

Note: I cannot deal with `pA`'s dependencies by hand: in my real scenario, there is countless dependencies I wouldn't install separately with `rpm`.

Comment: Additional question: What would happen if `pB-1.1.0-0` was versionned `pB-2.0.0-0` instead?

Comment: AFAIK You don't manage dependancies directly with options in `yum`. 
As you already said  [dependancies are managed](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/dependencies.html)  from the .spec file used to build an RPM package. You can modify the spec file for existing packages with [`rpmrebuild`](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/functions.html) though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do directly what you're asking, but you can install a specific version of the dependency *before* installing your primary package:

```
yum install pB-1.0.0-0
yum install pA
```

To prevent `pB` from being upgraded when updating the rest of the system, you can use the `versionlock` plugin for `yum`:

```
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum versionlock pB-*
```

This will lock the version of `pB` at whatever was installed when the lock was put in place. See [How to restrict yum to install or upgrade a package to a fixed specific package version?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/98873)

Edit: If you don't want to/can't deal with manual installation of the dependencies in their required versions, you can add the list of deps and their versions to `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list` to ensure specific versions get installed when you install `pA`.